# HP ProLiant ML350 Gen9 - Replace SFF cage with LFF cage to use specific HDD

Tags: hard-drive, storage, hardware, hp-proliant

Recently, I was given the task to replace the SFF HDDs in a [HP ProLiant ML350 Gen9 (PN: 776973-425, tower version)](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04346270&doctype=quickspecs&doclang=EN_US&searchquery=&cc=za&lc=en), and use LFF HDDs instead.

The HDDs are [4TB SAS 7.2K LFF SC DS HDD (PN: 872487-B21)](https://www.hpe.com/uk/en/product-catalog/servers/server-hard-drives/pip.specifications.hpe-server-midline-hard-drives.1009802853.html).
According to the "Technical Specifications", the HDD supports the HP ProLiant ML350 Gen10, with the "Low Profile (LP)/(LPC)" or "Raw Carrier(RW)/(AKA NPH)".
According to what I've read *somewhere*, the Gen9 supports the HDD as well.

I've tried to find information about these, and I can't find anything about those "cages".
All I've found was the "HP ML350 Gen9 8LFF Hot Plug Drive Cage Kit" (PN: 726547-B21; page 21 of the [Quick Specs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04346270&doctype=quickspecs&doclang=EN_US&searchquery=&cc=za&lc=en)), which isn't compatible with the HDDs listed.

The HDDs have already been bought, and can't be returned.

Which options do I have with this server and those HDDs?
Which part-numbers do I need to be able to use the HDDs in this server, if possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

A cage is what HP calls the kit that comprises of the slots for the HDD carriers, along with the backplane for the drives, and they can be fitted into "slots" in the front of servers to either kit them out for LFF or SFF drives, big 5-1/4" drives or something. Usually they are kitted out at the time of order, and it would be a lot of work to swap one.

I'd recommend calling HPE and tell them about your problems, the cage will be a bit more expensive direct from HPE, but they'll be able to tell you why supposedly those drives wouldn't work with that cage. I personally can't see why not.

Comment: We tried it. HPE wasn't helpful at all. They just told us to talk with our supplier. Our supplier told us to talk with HPE. None of them tried to find some solution for it.

Comment: Try talking to a vendor that specialises in used equipment, or try cold calling HPE support to get a different engineer, sometimes you can get another engineer that's more helpful that way! :)

Comment: We actually tried that, but I guess we can try anyway.